# How to make a page break close the container and repeat the header below with the rest of the content?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have several containers where various paragraphs will be inserted that will later be printed.
When doing the line break, the container is cut and its content is cut as well, thus showing.
[Current line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV2VM.png)

And what I need is for the container to close above, but below continue with its content and its header is repeated, so that it looks like the following
[Expected line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PzIi.png)

Code:

```
<div> <!-- Container -->
  <div>Header - Container 3</div> <!-- Header-->
  <div> <!-- Content -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit consectetur vel
      incidunt. Nisi pariatur ad earum quos possimus aspernatur ipsa tenetur! Dolorum officiis
      quos cupiditate! Cupiditate voluptate perspiciatis autem harum! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit
      amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit consectetur vel incidunt. Nisi pariatur
      ad earum quos possimus aspernatur ipsa tenetur! Dolorum officiis quos cupiditate!
      Cupiditate voluptate perspiciatis autem harum! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit consectetur vel incidunt. Nisi pariatur ad earum quos
      possimus aspernatur ipsa tenetur! Dolorum officiis quos cupiditate! Cupiditate voluptate
      perspiciatis autem harum!
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should write some JS code or change your direct HTML code based on your scenario. please provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could we get a snippet of your code for reference?

Secondly, [Flying Saucer xhtmlrenderer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/) repeats the THEAD on every page of PDF output, if you add the following to your CSS:

```
table {
        -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    }
```

(It's been working at least since the R8 release.)